# How do you disable an application specific hotkey, for example, "Command-P"?

Tags: keyboard

In many applications, Command-P is used to print. 
My fingers are accustomed to emacs settings and reflexively press Command-P not for printing but for browsing history. It's annoying to see the print pop-up window every time when I press Command-P. I don't need a shortcut to print.
How do you block a shortcut globally?

Comment: I'd call this more "system-wide" than "application-specific"...

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by remapping the Print shortcut to a different shortcut that is out of the way, unused and unlikely to be pressed.

1. Open System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts.
2. Click **+** to add a new shortcut.
3. Application: **All Applications**

   Menu Title: **Print…** <sub>(that's a 'proper' ellipses by the way, use copy-paste if necessary)</sub>

   Keyboard Shortcut: Set it to something out of the way.

   [image]
4. Click Add.

Now, the Print command is set to a random keyboard shortcut, freeing up ⌘P.

[image]

Comment: For me, all this does is make both the old as the new shortcut work. I want to disable Cmd + W in Cisco Packet Tracer which starts the activity wizard. As every other application in the universe closes the active tab with this shortcut i keep pressing it and needing to dismiss the wizard. Its really irritating me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use defaults to change the shortcut to something like U+200B (ZERO WIDTH SPACE):

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add Print... '\U200b'
```

`nil` would be triggered when pressing n in some applications like Audacity and `\0` would be triggered when pressing any key in Safari in 10.9.

I use a shell script like this to configure the shortcuts:

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Show Previous Tab"="~@\Uf702";
"Show Next Tab"="~@\Uf703";
"Minimize"="\U200b";
}'
defaults write com.apple.Finder NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Show Package Contents"="@\r";
}'
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a great tip. A note for dummies like me: it won't take effect until you relaunch the application.